# Negative lookahead skips the negated expression

Tags: regex

I have a text with a structure like this:

```html
<section id="TP-1">
<h3>1. One</h3>
<p>Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.</p>
</section>

<hr class="sections" />

<section id="TP-2">
<h3>2. Two</h3>
<p>Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.</p>
<hr class="footnote" />
<p class="footnote"></p>
</section>
```

I need to add an `id` attribute to the `p` tags belonging to the `footnote` class, and its value should be based on the `id` of the parent `section` tag. This is what I wrote:

```
<section id="TP-(\d+?)">((.|\n)+?)(?!</section>)<p class="footnote"
```

The problem is that the match is not the desired one and includes `</section>` while I used negative lookahead. Here is the match:

```html
<section id="TP-1">
<h3>1. One</h3>
<p>Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.</p>
</section>

<hr class="sections" />

<section id="TP-2">
<h3>2. Two</h3>
<p>Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.</p>
<hr class="footnote" />
<p class="footnote"
```

While I expected this:

```html
<section id="TP-2">
<h3>2. Two</h3>
<p>Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.</p>
<hr class="footnote" />
<p class="footnote"
```

Here you can check the regex: https://regex101.com/r/qGIUYd/1

Comment: `<section id="TP-(\d+)">(?:[\s\S](?!<\/?section?))+<p class="footnote">` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your negative lookahead occurs after `(.|\n)+?` (which btw you should replace with `.` and `s` flag) that will match everything it can until the next `<p class="footnote"`.

Put the negative lookahead *inside* the quantified expression:

```
/ <section id="TP-(\d+?)">(.(?!<\/section>))+?<p class="footnote" /gms
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/NBVy90/1